# how to get the uid of person who is in relationship or commited or married to user with php sdk

Tags: facebook, relationship, userid

how to get uid of person with whom the user is in relation or married with fql if the required permisson is granted  ?
I need to get user id of user with whom the person is in relation to .. i am using php sdk

Answer (score 1):

The information you are looking for is in the user Graph API endpoint. It is called `significant_other`. You'll be able to [use it with the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), like this -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id?fields=id,name,significant_other
```

With FQL you can use the [`significant_other_id` field of the user table.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) Like this -

```
select uid, name,significant_other_id from user where uid=user_id
```